# How to generate OpenAPI document/SwaggerDoc for individual controller in asp.net-core 3.1

Tags: asp.net-core, swagger, openapi, swashbuckle, swashbuckle.aspnetcore

I've 30+ asp.net-core web-API controllers each having multiple versions. Need a way to generate `SwaggerDoc` **per controller per version.**

Example on end points:

```
<cname>/v1/Employees,
<cname>/v2/Employees,
<cname>/v1/Departments,
<cname>/v1/Courses,
```

**Output**: When I do a http Get for `<cname>/v1/Employees/_meta` it should **return a Swagger Doc in Json format with 200 status code**. Similarly, for `<cname>/v2/Employees/_meta` should return similar o/p **but only for v2 controller methods.**

**Library used**:
Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger

**Tried with success**: I've answered below with my approach and seeking for more elegant way/better approaches, if any.

Answer (score 1):

[Seeking for more elegant way/better approaches, improvements, if any]

**My/OP's approach:**

Annotate/attribute individual controllers with (if controller has multiple version, then use the same tag at method level instead of class level):

```
[ApiExplorerSettings(GroupName = "v1/Employees")]
```

This creates logical grouping of controllers.

While registering services, register a key-value pair with `SwaggerDoc` using `SwaggerGenOptions`:

```
//<Group name> -> <Doc Info> 

public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.Configure<SwaggerGenOptions>(o => o.SwaggerDoc("v1/Employees", new OpenApiInfo
    {
        Title = "Employees Service",
        Description = "An API to expose Employees info.",
        Version = "v1"
    }));
    
    services.Configure<SwaggerGenOptions>(o => o.SwaggerDoc("v2/Employees", new OpenApiInfo
    {
        Title = "Employees Service",
        Description = "An API to expose Employees info.",
        Version = "v2"
    }));
}
```

Now, below add Ad-hoc endpoints:

```
builder.Configure((app, endpoints) =>
{
    //Takes care requests for both v1, v2 employees versions .
    endpoints.MapGet("v{version}/Employees/_meta", GetSwaggerDocument()); 
    
    //similiarly other endpoints.
    endpoints.MapGet("v{version}/Departments/_meta", GetSwaggerDocument());
    endpoints.MapGet("v{version}/Courses/_meta", GetSwaggerDocument());
});

private static RequestDelegate GetSwaggerDocument() => async context =>
{
    var provider = context.RequestServices.GetService<ISwaggerProvider>();

    context.Response.StatusCode = 200;
    context.Response.ContentType = MediaTypeNames.Application.Json;

    var requestPath = context.Request.Path.Value.Split('/');

    await context.Response.WriteAsync(
        provider?
            .GetSwagger($"{requestPath[1]}/{requestPath[2]}")
            .SerializeAsJson(OpenApiSpecVersion.OpenApi3_0));
};
```

Now, querying for `<cname>/v1/Employees/_meta` and `<cname>/v2/Employees/_meta`, etc., **should return 200 status code with Json Swagger doc for all registered docs. per controller, per version**